# Does Scoundrel give a bonus to gold find?

Tags: diablo-iii

Basically what the title says. I think he at one point told me that if I want more gold I should bring him next time. So was wondering if he actually has a passive bonus to dropped gold (not counting the 20% from possible gear) or was it just a random remark?

Not sure if this is a duplicate, there are a lot of follower questions and couldn't find one similar to this.

Comment: Originally the Scoundrel had a skill called "Rain of Gold". I'm guessing this is what he's referring to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alas, it's just another one of his attempts to swindle more than his fair share - the Scoundrel gives no visible bonus to gold find.

However, like all of your followers, if you were to equip him with gold find items, you'll find that a small percentage of that bonus carries over to yours. (20%, to be precise!)

Comment: This can be said by any of your followers though.

Answer (score -2):

When this game first came out, each follower had a bonus, and yes the scoundrel had a bonus to gold find as his bonus. But that was literally in the first year maybe 2 years when the game first came out.

Comment: so is that to say "yes he does" or "yes he did but not anymore"? and if not anymore, when was it removed?